# Display image in recycler view similar to facebook timeline

Tags: android, facebook, image, android-recyclerview

I am creating an android application, I am stuck at one point. I want to display posts as it gets displayed in facebook timeline. Post may have images or may not. I have created a card view for other post elements and I am able to display them in posts. I have the image links sent from server for the post images, now I want to download images and display on particular post which has image in it. How can I do this? If user has 10 posts, there may be image in one or two. How can I check which post has image and then display the image in that post after downloading it. Can any one please help me in this.

Please let me know if you need more information. My card view is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/human_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewUser"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewUser"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="titleText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewNoOfDays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="No of Days"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewUser"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewUser"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPostDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewUser"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="ABCDE"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonPin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_pin_grey600_18dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewPostDescription"
            />








    </RelativeLayout>






</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You must be getting some json from server. Check for the image key in json. If it exists and it's value isn't null, use some image loading library like Glide from bumptech to load image in your image view, else set image view visibility to gone in your viewholder. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes very similar to this. can you give me a link for me to use that. i ma downloading images from the link  given in json and is taking lot of time.. so that would be help full

Comment: This is the library i mentioned: https://github.com/bumptech/glide . Scroll down and you'll find how to use this. This will download image for you and also set it in the image view. If it still takes a lot of time to show the image, it could be that your image is very heavy, given you have a decent connection. Glide also has an option to put a placeholder image until the actual image loads.

Comment: Current i am extracting image links from the response and I have stored them in array list and them I am downloading all images, i am not getting how to check to which post the image belongs

Comment: If you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are extracting the image links? Ideally you should make a Post (or what you like to call it) class which stores the content and image. Now you pass a List<Post> object to your list adapter and then set the content and image in the adapter, in the getView. This will each post object will have its image url inside it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96459/discussion-between-gitter-and-keshav).

Answer (score 1):

This is how i managed to get this working.

Adapter Class:

```
public class StoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Success> successList;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private Context mContext;

    public StoriesAdapter(Context context, List<Success> successList) {
        this.successList = successList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.success_list, parent, false);
        StoryItemViewHolder vh = new StoryItemViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        final Success success = successList.get(position);
        StoryItemViewHolder holder = (StoryItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
        // Feed image
        if (!success.getThumbnailUrl().equals("null")) {//check if null
            holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(success.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
            holder.thumbNail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.thumbNail.setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            holder.thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != successList ? successList.size() : 0);
    }

}
```

And the viewHolder:

```
public class StoryItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public FeedImageView thumbNail;

    public StoryItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.thumbNail= (FeedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one you are looking for, [facebook](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)
like `cardview` . It test if the image fetch from the server is `null`. This is a responsive to images size as well.